# Ruby class running methods

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby Class with a method that basically runs a list of other methods inside the same Class.  Eg:

```
def tidy
    delete_gallery_items
    delete_collections
    import_collections
    assign_albums_to_collections
    reorder_albums
    rebuild_gallery_items
    reposition_collections
end
```

Will these all run one after another or could there be a scenario when one of the later ones starts before a previous one has finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One will be called after the other. It is not possible that a later one gets called before it is its turn.

I can only think of an edge case like that when those methods internally start new threads then a later method might process its thread faster than an earlier method. But that doesn't change the fact that the methods will be called one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you did ask.

```
class C
  def a
    self.class.alias_method :b_old, :b
    self.class.alias_method :c_old, :c
    self.class.alias_method :b, :c_old
    self.class.alias_method :c, :b_old
    puts "a"
  end

  def b
    puts "b"
  end

  def c
    puts "c"
  end

  def tidy
    a
    b
    c
  end
end
```

```
C.new.tidy
  #=> nil
```

displays:

```
a
c
b
```

Comment: I believe this also answers "should I do something just because I can?"